# How can I mount an ext4 file system on OS X?

Tags: macos, unix

Is there a safe, stable application for reading from and writing to [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) file systems on Mac OS X?

If not, what's the best way to access the contents of an ext4 file system on Mac OS X?

Comment: It would be more than helpful if you specified what version of OS X you are running. There are compatibility issues with the solutions available depending on OS revision.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The answer depends on you willingness to invest in commercial software:

**If you don’t mind spending some money on a commercial product**, [Paragon’s *extFS for Mac*](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) will give you read and write access to ext2 / ext3 / ext4 file systems. The current version supports all versions of OS X / macOS from 10.10 upwards.

**If you are looking for a free solution**, you can setup a Linux virtual machine, mount your volume(s) there and share it / them via [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) or (S)FTP. [This post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-os-x-read-ext3-ext4-external-usb-hard-disk-partition/) has some details on how to achieve this using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), a free virtual machine application. Note this is not exactly a lightweight solution, even if using a [prebuilt VirtualBox VM](https://www.osboxes.org/virtualbox-images/) will spare you installing and configuring a Linux distro from scratch.

Comment: Surely there's a free nonvm solution?

Comment: https://www.osboxes.org/ provides newer versions vs virtualboxes.org.

Comment: Can you really mount a physical external drive in a VirtualBox VM, at least in the free version of it? I don't see a way. In any case creating the VM is the easy part, mounting the drive within it is the hard part which needs to be answered.

Comment: @q.undertow [yes you can](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) (though not through a GUI). I beg to differ on the “needs to be answered” part, as that was not specified in OP’s question; we could also be speaking of a virtual disk image

Comment: @kopischke thanks, that is good to know. I myself am trying to recover data from my Linux external drive, it is way too big to create an image file from it, I really need to read the physical drive.

Comment: Update: I tried the VirtualBox solution, and it is harder than the documentation linked above makes it seem. The snag is in the "attach" step: VBoxManage complains that it cannot find my VM (I tried specifying it both by name and by uuid). Then, if I try to "register" the existing .vbox file, it complains that such a VM already exists! At this point I felt that proceeding was too risky, and went back to plan a sneaker net solution (only with a 16G SD card instead of a 1M floppy, LOL).

Comment: I would avoid Paragon's solution. I have a drive with a large number of files (about 300 in the root folder), and it only shows a fraction of them. I tried the same drive with Ubuntu (running in a VM on the same machine) and it sees all the files.

Comment: I would avoid proprietary software in general. And I would be even more cautious to trust a black box software for accessing _and manipulating_ a filesystem. Especially when multiple people complain about its buggy behavior.

Comment: VirtualBox not currently (2023) working well with Apple silicon (M1/M2): still in beta

Answer (score 42):

Building on Ken's answer: I used [fuse4x](http://fuse4x.github.io/) and [fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2) successfully, and I recommend fuse-ext2 over ext4fuse. fuse-ext2 provides write access while ext4fuse provides only read access. Note that despite its name, fuse-ext2 supports EXT2/EXT3/EXT4.

ext4fuse was a hassle for me, because it requires manual compilation and has no support for fuse4x options that would allow me to set access control. fuse-ext2 provides downloadable packages, and the 0.0.7 version worked just fine. I copied a few large ISOs over without any problem.

Edit: It should be mentioned that as of 12/22, the fuse-ext2 Github page still lists unstable write support as a bug and recommends not using it "unless you have nothing to lose."

Comment: can fuse-ext2 mount things as writable or only readonly?

Comment: As of today, fuse4x declares itself deprecated, and guides users to [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io). fuse-ext2 depends on macFUSE right now; I assume that it migrated its dependency from fuse4x to macFUSE. So the “fuse4x options” argument is no longer valid.

Answer (score 27):

One can also install OSXFUSE completely via the [brew](http://brew.sh) command line package manager:

```
brew install homebrew/fuse/ext4fuse
```

Note that the installation tells certain commands need to be run as 'sudo' in addition to this.

---

With Yosemite better have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28106806/299421). And then make sure the directory is readable by your user by doing [this](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/27). For it to work I had to use the wheel group like this:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership $(whoami)
```

Comment: Years later, `$ brew info ext2fuse
ext2fuse: stable 0.8.1 (bottled)
Compact implementation of ext2 file system using FUSE
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fuse
Disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!
Not installed`

Answer (score 23):

With recent changes to homebrew, this should be as simple as:

```
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
```

You may have to reboot.

[ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse) is read-only, unfortunately. And you may need to [use a flag](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/36#issuecomment-237390665) to get it to work as a normal user.

Others viewing this question may be interested in [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/). I'm not aware of an OS X port, but considering that VirtualBox has an API, it's not out of the question.

I wonder why no one has written a compatibility layer to allow Linux kernel filesystem code to run in userspace/fuse. Or has someone?

Comment: Some updates as of `osxfuse` was removed from homebrew and `ext4fuse` moved on to depend on the new - branched(?) - opensource version `macfuse`: (1) `brew install --cask macfuse` (2) use the patched `ext4fuse.rb`  in this link (https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/66)

Answer (score 19):

For recent versions of MacOS [ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse) works stably for *[read access only](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/wiki/Write-Support)*. While other answers already give some usage examples I'll repeat it once again with some important details:

1. Install [macFUSE](https://macfuse.io) manually or with:

```bash
brew install macfuse
```

2. Install [ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse) with:

```bash
brew install ext4fuse
```

> <sup>If the command above fails with `Error: ext4fuse has been disabled` then follow the steps at https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/66#issuecomment-819943409</sup>

3. You can mount as a regular user but that will only provide access to world-readable files. To access all files you'll need to  `sudo`, e.g.:

```bash
sudo ext4fuse -o allow_other,defer_permissions /dev/disk2s1
```

> NOTE: <sub>`-o allow_other,defer_permissions` are needed in order to allow accessing the files from finder or terminal as a regular user.</sub>

4. You might also need to add your user to the operators group:

```bash
# $USER is an ootb env variable that stores your mac user name
sudo dscl . append /Groups/operator GroupMembership $USER
```

The bash script below can be used to automate the mounting. It will loop over the Linux partitions found and prompt to mount them one by one. The mount points will be created  under `~/mnt/<device-name>` (if not present):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for device in $(diskutil list | awk '/Linux/  {print $NF}') ; do
    
    read -p ">>> Found linux device: $device. Mount? y/n <<< " answer

    if [[ "$answer" =~ [yY] ]]; then
        mount_point="$HOME/mnt/$device"

        mkdir -p $mount_point
        echo "Mounting device $device at $mount_point..."

        sudo ext4fuse -o allow_other,defer_permissions /dev/$device ${mount_point}
        
        status=$?

        if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo "Mounted successfully at ${mount_point}"
            
            read -p "Open in Finder? y/n " show_in_finder
            echo "***IMPORTANT: TO UNMOUNT USE***: diskutil umount ${mount_point}"

            if [[ "$show_in_finder" =~ [yY] ]]; then
                open "$mount_point"
            fi
        else
            echo "\nERROR mounting device $device!"
            echo "Is macFUSE installed? see https://macfuse.io"
            echo "is ext4fuse installed? (brew install ext4fuse) https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse"
            echo "See also: https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/66#issuecomment-819943409"
        fi  
    fi
done
```

To unmount you can use e.g. `diskutil umount /dev/disk2s1` — if you get a message that unmounting failed then you can force unmounting with `diskutil umount force /dev/disk2s1`, although it is recommended to close the apps that are using the files on the disk and retry without `force`.

If you happen to have files owned by `_lpoperator` (apparently they are created when you use rsync with preserve group option), then the following command will allow accessing those files:

```bash
/usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -a everyone -t group _lpoperator
```

#### Original answer for Yosemite and older *(deprecated)*

Two packages are needed in order to enable EXT2/3/4 support on OSX: [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/) and [FUSE-EXT2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/).

The **homebrew** formulas for OSXFUSE and FUSE-EXT2 did not seem to work on either mavericks or yosemite.

What did work was the following:

1. Manually downloading and installing the OSXFUSE DMG from http://osxfuse.github.io/. **IMPORTANT**: Once you launch the PKG installer, make sure you select *MacFUSE Compatibility Layer* in the wizard (it is not enabled by default) - without it mounting fails.
2. Manually download FUSE-EXT2 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/ or for Sierra/El Capitan from https://github.com/gpz500/fuse-ext2/releases and run the PKG installer.

Once OSXFUSE and FUSE-EXT2 are installed you can mount ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions as described in other answers:

1. Find the device name for the EXT partition you want to mount (e.g. `disk0s2` in the example below, (UPDATE) in some MacOS versions ext3/ext4 partitions might be labelled *Microsoft Basic Data* and not *Linux*):

```bash
# diskutil list | grep Linux
1:     Linux_Swap    8.2 GB     disk0s1
2:     Linux         119.9 GB   disk0s2
```

2. Mount the partition to an existing mount point:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/ext4
sudo mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk0s2 /Volumes/ext4
```

Mounting as a regular user does not seem to work hence the need for `sudo`.

## ❗️ Known issues and limitations

Apparently, after waking from sleep mode ext4 fuse mounts stop working and trying to remount throws an error because the previous mount is still present. The workaround is to do a `diskutil umount <mount_point>` or `diskutil umount force <mount_point>` before remounting. An alternative workaround is to temporarily prevent sleeping while you are using the partitions with something like `caffeinate -sdi`.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately get the error `FUSE-EXT2 could not mount /dev/disk2s2 at /Volumes/ext4 because the following problem occurred:` (but there is no problem description or reference). I have installed the Compability Layer addon. I'm on macOS Sierra so tried the Github gzp500 version.

Answer (score 12):

If you're wondering what the command line is to mount an ext4 partition using fuse and ext2fuse (e.g. when installed using MacPorts `port install ext2fuse`) - then firstly you need to work out where the Linux partition is:

```
diskutil list
```

This will list all partitions for all disks and amongst them you should see the relevant ones listed under the TYPE column as Linux. Combine the diskX and partition number Y like this /dev/diskXsY - e.g:

```
mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk1s2 ~/my_mount_point
```

It may complain about not being able to write to the log file but it should still mount the partition into your home mount point. But if you want to mount the partition into a system directory then you need to run it as root e.g:

```
sudo mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk1s2 /sys_mount_point
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
sudo ext2fuse /dev/disk1s2 /sys_mount_point
```

**Update**: More recently I've found that fuse-ext2 has problems with certain newer ext4 features, so instead it is better to use **ext4fuse** (`port install ext4fuse` or `brew install ext4fuse`). Use the ext4fuse command directly:

```
ext4fuse /dev/disk1s2 ~/mount_point
```

Also as mentioned by Timothy in the comments you usually only need to use `sudo` if you're mounting outside your home directory or the disk (/dev/diskX) is only accessible by root:

```
sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk1s2 /sys_mount_point
```

It should be noted that you can only access that mounted filesystem as root/sudo. e.g.

```
sudo ls /sys_mount_point
```

And to unmount the filesystem you just use normal `umount` command (with sudo if used to mount the partition):

```
umount ~/mount_point
```

Comment: You only need to access the drive as root if you mount it outside your home directory. You can `cd ~`, `mkdir mnt`, `ext4fuse /dev/diskXsY mnt`, `ls -la mnt` without sudo/root.

Comment: mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/fuse-ext2.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_fuse-ext2 for ...: No such file or directory

Comment: ext4fuse is virtually useless. It coughs up endless permissions and read errors when you try to read anything. It was zero help to me in actually getting the files off and ext4 volume.

Answer (score 11):

Just for the record, I have tested Paragon ExtFS driver (trial version) on my MacBook Pro to write to ext4 partition in Linux. I found that the driver was very unstable, and it created corruptions to the filesystem that `fsck` was not able to repair neither in Linux nor in Disk Utility.

My idea was to have access to my `/home` partition from Mac OS X using this Paragon driver, but I don't suggest to do this setup. So far, I have my `/home` partition in Linux formatted to `hfsplus` with no journaling, and then I can access my files from Mac OS X. Of course, from time to time I get some problems in my FS but is not very frequent. However, I don't suggest this setup either (at least that you have an up to date backup for your daily work).

Finally, I believe that Paragon is more suitable maybe to use for external hard disks but anyways it is not very reliable for being software which license is expensive.

**Update:** As of May 2015, I have formatted my /home to ext4, and I mount the filesystem using fuse-ext2 in combination with FUSE for OS X. I can access the ext4 partition to read and write. It is more solid setup than the one I previously described above.

Comment: I can confirm the last entry here where the Paragon ExtFS driver can make some bad trouble on your linux drives. For me, who is dualbooting OSX and Linux, paragon created corruptions on my / device. This was easy to resolve but however thats not a stable solution...

Comment: Further bad experience with Paragon ExtFS driver. Consistent kernel panics leading to system rebooting, corruption of the files system (luckily fsck on Linux box did work). Tried on two different external drives with same results.

Answer (score 11):

You can boot [Linux VM](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu) quickly on your OS X using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). You require to install VM provider such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) either via .dmg file from the site or using [brew cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/vagrant.rb).

Once you have `vagrant` command installed, run this in any selected folder:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

<sup>This will generate `Vagrantfile` config file and `.vagrant` folder.</sup>

and you'll have Linux box booted within few minutes (downloaded from [Atlas Hashicorp](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) repository).

Then **connect to the box** via command: `vagrant ssh` and **try to mount your device** inside Linux.

By default your current folder will be synched with `/vagrant` folder in VM. For more advanced options, you can modify [`Vagrantfile`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/) with required configuration.

So if you mount your filesystem within `/vagrant` folder, it will be automatically synched back to your macOS.

---

Alternatively you just need to install a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), run the GUI app, install and boot a minimal version of Linux e.g. [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) in order to achieve the same as explained above.

---

Above non-native solution are not ideal, but at least your macOS would be more stable rather than installing unstable kernel extensions which may cause a lot of system crashes.

Comment: Ran with `vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox` as `ubuntu/vivid64` is not available anymore.

Comment: Try use `ubuntu/trusty64` instead.

Answer (score 8):

I had an ext4 formatted USB drive that I was able to mount after I installed [osxfuse](http://osxfuse.github.com/). Reading from it works great, but I am not sure if writing is safe.

Also, for moving files from OS X's filesystem ([HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)) to ext4, you may first want to [remove those hidden .DS_Store files](http://danilo.ariadoss.com/how-to-recursively-remove-ds_store-files-on-mac-os-x/) the OS X filesystem sneaks in as they occasionally cause bad [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

```
find /my/data/to/move -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

It is better than having to fix them after with an [fsck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) command.

Answer (score 6):

There is also e2fsprogs available in MacPorts. I haven't tested it yet myself but looks promising.

Comment: None of the e2fsprogs let you do this. Apparently one of them used to, but it's no longer in the package. The tools in this package *do* let you run `fsck` and `newfs` to repair and create an ext filesystem, but they don't let you mount or read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at --> https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2

This is what I will be trying next.

For ext2, there is a macports version: https://ports.macports.org/port/ext2fuse/summary

There is an ext4 module for osxfuse (which you can install via macports) but it is read only!

The multitude of versions is a bit confusing but at one point I had managed to get it to work, I will be trying again and updating this answer if it does. :)

osxfuse is available on macports and as a standalone package. I don't know which one works best yet on newer OS X versions, but I prefer macports for my free software on OS X.

Comment: ext4fuse is technically read-only, but it doesn't even always allow you to read, it coughs up a lot of obscure errors and basically stands in your way at least as much as it helps.