# Mounting Ext3 filesystem with OS X 10.7.4

Tags: filesystem

I'm trying to mount an Ext3 external USB hard drive in OS X 10.7.4. I installed OSXFUSE (with macfuse compability layer), which worked fine. After that I tried to install EXT2FS but the install processs always aborted.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your question is about how to mount an ExtFS file system, check [this possible duplicate](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29842/11948).

Comment: Are you looking to solve the abort or remove osx fuse or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Paragon's ExtFS driver](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) in OS X Mavericks (and Mountain Lion previously) with full read/write access. This has worked for me with ext3 and ext4 file systems.

My only concern would be if you are mounting your Linux root (or any other system root) and you are therefore able to touch sensitive files (`/etc/` comes to mind) that may stop working (Linux does not boot, etc) if the wrong permissions get applied. The solution to this is to mount read-only but I cannot say that Paragon's software really has that as a built-in option. The default mode (as is with OS X in general, except for the built-in NTFS driver) is read/write.

Also, do not expect performance in any case. I tried to use my external drive with iTunes and the performance was intolerable.