# How to mount ext4 partition on OS X 10.8.2?

Tags: unix, filesystem, mount

I'm  new to OS X, I was using Ubuntu till now. All my data are stored on an external drive formated as ext4 system file. Is there any other way to acces this data than installing Virtual Box? I'm using OS X 10.8.2.

I was trying solution form [How can I mount an ext4 file system on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x)

Terminal output:

```
MacBook-Pro-Marek:Downloads user$ ./ext4fuse-24810919 /dev/disk1 Linux
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfuse.2.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/user/Downloads/./ext4fuse-24810919
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I was trying also [this](http://adennyh.blogspot.com/2011/11/mounting-linux-hdd-ext4ext3ex2-in-osx.html), with the same result (`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfuse.2.dylib`)

I found also [this](http://blog.applegrew.com/2011/12/access-ext3ext2-file-system-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7/), where it's said that most of available solutions don't work for Lion, but this solution says how to mount ext2 or ext3 file system, and not ext4.

I don't know how should I load this library and if the problem is in the library or the solutions which don't work for my OS X distribution.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Instead of installing ext4fuse yourself, try using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install it. (This is the method recommended by the developer.)
Read the developer's install page [here](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse).

Incidentally, if you're from Linux you're probably used to using apt-get to install things. [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) describes itself as "The missing package manager for OS X", and makes it a lot easier to install a lot of linux ports. (For example, `brew install ext4fuse` will install ext4fuse. The advantage of homebrew is that it will automatically download and install dependencies for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I should say that couldn't find a way to acces my data, I've gave up OS X... But I hope your answer will help somebody else...