# Write in NTFS using Mavericks

Tags: homebrew, macos, ntfs

I was able to read and write NTFS filesystems normally in Mountain Lion, but after the upgrade this stopped to work.

I installed ntfs-3g and fuse4x using homebrew in Mountain Lion and followed the instructions displayed by homebrew to finish the installation of fuse4x kernel extension.

To try to solve this problem I removed ntfs-3g, fuse4x and fuse4x-kext and reinstalled them. But this didn't solve my problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 87):

I found the proper way to do this (also works for *Yosemite*):

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and [cask](http://caskroom.io) if you don't already have them:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

Uninstall any previous versions of `osxfuse` (unsigned kexts are banned now):

```
brew cask uninstall osxfuse
```

Update Homebrew and install `osxfuse` and `ntfs-3g`

```
brew update
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install ntfs-3g
```

You need to create a symlink for `mount_ntfs`, in order to make drives mount automatically:

```
sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs
```

Comment: Note that not everyone has homebrew installed by default. Could you please add a link to the homebrew website explaining that you need to install that to get the `brew` command?

Comment: works like a charm !

Comment: ntfs-3g is a FUSE filesystem, so it runs in user space - while it's free and probably works fine (used to use it on Linux a lot), you may find a commercial NTFS driver such as Tuxera's is faster if you do a lot of read/write to NTFS filesystems.

Comment: Didn't work for me... I get this: "diskarbitrationd[21]: unable to mount /dev/disk1s1 (status code 0x0000000D)."

Comment: Had some permissions issues. Make sure you everything is linked ```brew upgrade fuse4x```
```brew upgrade ntfs-3g```

Comment: ntfs-3g seems to require osxfuse which conflicts with fuse4x ..

Comment: didn't work for me, got `The OSXFUSE library version this program is using is incompatible with the loaded OSXFUSE kernel extension.` Installing OSXFUSE manually form http://osxfuse.github.io/ fixed this issue

Comment: Wonderful. Works fine. Had a warning though of unidentified 'core'.

Comment: Be advised that the current version of osxfuse contains a nasty bug that leaves broken directories behind in /Volumes.

Comment: Worked fine in Mavericks. Had to use ``brew install`` instead of ``brew upgrade``. Also, didn't have to explicitly install ``osxfuse`` first, as it is a ``ntfs-3g`` dependency and brew installs it automatically upon ``brew install ntfs-3g``.

Comment: If you are looking for a safe, working homebrew-powered way for making NTFS R/W work on _Yosemite_, check my anwser on another question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180248/50394
@mattburns You can copy from that anwser to improve this one, if you like.

Comment: Thanks @cubuspl42, that worked for me (I had to tweak your answer with a few edits). Cheers.

Comment: Does `brew cask uninstall osxfuse` uninstall pure homebrew, non-cask version of osxfuse that most Mavericks users have installed?

Comment: It's probably less brittle to replace the last command with this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs`

Comment: `$ sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original
Password:
mv: rename /sbin/mount_ntfs to /sbin/mount_ntfs.original: Operation not permitted`

Comment: If you get following error while installing ntfs-3g "Error: No available formula for ntfs-3g", try installing it by running: brew install homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g

Answer (score 13):

This is so easy and you **don't** need to install any 3rd party application or driver. No reboot required.

1. Find out the name of your "Volume"
2. Open Terminal
3. Create or Update your /etc/fstab file. Replace "My040Passport" with the name of your "Volume". you can do this by typing **sudo vi /etc/fstab** into Terminal. You will be prompted for your password.

   ```
   #
   # Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)
   #
   # Failure to do so is unsupported and may be destructive.
   #
   LABEL=My\040Passport none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
   ```
4. Unplug your external harddrive and then plug it back in
5. You will NOT see your HDD listed in the Finder anymore you must open it in from within Terminal with the below steps.
6. Open Terminal, enter 3 commands below and use your own Volume name in the 3rd command

   ```
   cd /Volumes
   ls 
   open My\ Passport
   ```

   Command 1 will Change your current directory.
   Command 2 will list Volumes, the one you're interested in will be listed here.
   Command 3 will open your Volume in Finder.
7. Since you won't see the HDD in the Finder, let's add a link to it onto your Desktop. Open Terminal, enter this command replacing the Volume name, and replace the destination as well if desired.

   ```
   ln -s /Volumes/My\ Passport/ ~/Desktop/hdd
   ```

Comment: To bad that no icon is displayed on the desktop. I wonder why that is.

Comment: @grgarside You can add it to your desktop with just one more command. `sudo ln -s /Volumes ~/Desktop/Volumes` via [this article](http://learnaholic.me/2013/11/11/enable-ntfs-write-on-mac-os-x-mavericks/)

Comment: I have also tried this solution from some blog and it worked!!! However, until I was copying using terminal, all was working fine. As soon as I tried copying using Finder to a folder, containing minimum of 50GB of Data, in external HDD, content of the target folder went empty without any notification or error. :( Now that folder always seems empty.

Comment: This is the best way to write to NTFS volumes. Using 3rd party applications like Paragon NTFS or osxfuse will mess up your modules which leads to frequent kernel panics. I had the same issue when trying Paragon extFS for ext4. See this thread for related issues: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x (the thread is for ext4, but ntfs is basically the same when you're using a 3rd party application)

Comment: There is small drawback....you need to repeat this step for *every single* drive you insert...a little bit of a pain, but well...no biggie...

Comment: Consider `sudo vifs` instead of `sudo vi /etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same setup as you, and since upgrading to 10.9 I can't write to NTFS. The solution I ended up going with (at least for the short term,) was to use [Paragon's NTFS for Mac® OS X 11](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/download.html). It seems to work fine, and has a 10 day free trial.

Hopefully a better method will be found soon, but I got tired of messing with it.

Another option that I didn't try was to edit the `/etc/fstab` file. The following is from [NTFS Write Support On OS X Mountain Lion](http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/04/21/ntfs-write-support-on-os-x-mountain-lion/):

- Uninstall other 3rd-party NTFS software, like Paragon, Tuxera or NTFS-3G.
- Edit `/etc/fstab` (you can do this with `sudo vi /etc/fstab`)
  Add the following line:
  **LABEL=”VOLUME_NAME_WITHOUT_QUOTES” none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse**
- Now, just unmount and re-mount the disk

Comment: I tried the other approach you mentioned, no luck:(

Comment: Here is what I did for my Bootcamp drive: `LABEL=BOOTCAMP none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse`. It works well on 10.9 Maverick. If you are using Seagate HDD, you can also download the free [Seagate NTFS driver](http://www.seagate.com/support/external-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/backup-plus-desk/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/)

Comment: after this, volume is not displaying in finder window. to access it goto "/Volumes" from 

Menu->Go->"Go To Folder"

menu. Also you can add this volume to sidebar to future easy access..

Comment: Just as a warning to others, I used this and then had backblaze backing up the drive (constant activity for days) and eventually my drive freaked out, crashed OSX, and even after I removed the drive I was not able to get OSX to be stable again until I removed the /etc/fstab file. I don't recommend this option on Mavericks

Comment: @HaiFengKao Does that only work with Seagate drives?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes. The driver will detect your HDD brand.

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of [macfuse-core-10.5-2.1.9](http://www.tuxera.com/mac/macfuse-core-10.5-2.1.9.dmg), and [ntfs-3g-2010.10.2-macosx](http://www.4shared.com/get/89egzQiE/ntfs-3g-2010102-macosx.html) on OS X Mavericks and I am able to write to a NTFS drive.

- Firstly Install macfuse-core-10.5-2.1.9
- Then install ntfs-3g-2010.10.2-macosx
- After installations, let's open the NTFS-3G

  - System Preference > NTFS-3G
  - Click [enable]
- Finally, let's unmount your target NTFS disk and mount it again

Even if you go the TimeOut message, you are in the right direction already. 
Let's try to create file and folder to your NTFS harddrive.

Comment: Can you detail the steps to arrange this combination? Simply installing both doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the "Click [enable]". For the TimeOut message, you got FuseWait I think.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [NTFS-FREE for OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsfree/files/NTFS-free-10.8.2.pkg/download) software and reboot you Mac. This worked for me on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mavericks for me either.

Comment: Worked great for me on OSX 10.9.3 (Mavericks). Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Using MacPorts:

```
sudo port install fuse4x ntfs-3g
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/ntfsmountpoint
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is aimed at latest compatibility for **OS X 10.11 El Capitan**.

1. Install latest osxfuse (3.x.x) from https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases or from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with `brew cask install osxfuse`.
2. Install latest NTFS-3G (2015.3.14) from brew (homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g).

As follow:

```
brew install ntfs-3g
```

3. Link NTFS-3G to boot after temporary disabling System Integrity Protection.

As follow:

```
[reboot by holding CMD+R to get in recovery mode]
csrutil disable
[reboot normally]
sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs
[reboot by holding CMD+R to get in recovery mode]
csrutil enable
[reboot normally]
```

## installation alternative

For building NTFS-3G from [source edge](https://sourceforge.net/p/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g/ci/edge/tree/) (2015.9.30): check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979396/compiling-ntfs-3g-for-os-x/31014256#31014256)

Comment: It worked. But its not showing drive on desktop or even in devices... just showing in /Volumes

It use to show up in maverick

Comment: @AkarshSatija Maybe try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180248/62697 or https://gist.github.com/mrpatiwi/8bca2f20b140150f1cbd

Comment: @AkarshSatija I found the issue: osxfuse 3.0.x is required instead of 2.8.x

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Mavericks, but in Lion I have write access to NTFS file systems using [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/), a free & open-source alternative to commercial solutions by Tuxera or Paragon.

Notice this is **NOT**  [the old MacFUSE project](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/); which is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

SEAGATE USERS:
Your in luck! let's do it the safe way
For seagate hard disk owners alone, download the free driver here!
http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/

OTHER USERS:
1.Fuse/NTFS-3G drivers is a good option.
http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-writing-to-ntfs-hard.html
2. If you're a geek there are ton of other options using terminal commands. But be warned, you can run into issues during future updates etc.

FOR PEN-DRIVES:
If it is for a pen-drive(or any smaller USB sticks), you could simply format it to FAT32 
For larger hard drives, FAT32 is not a good option, since it has file-size limits etc

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest version of the old MacFuse for OS X.

What I did was to reinstall my NTFS-3G and download and install [Fuse for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Following Pawel's answer fixed the issue for me in Mavericks

```
brew update
brew install fuse4x
brew install ntfs-3g
sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.orig
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs
brew info fuse4x-kext
```

Dont symlink fuse4x even though the linking fails as ntfs-3g also tries to create the same link.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Mavericks(10.9.5). I had formated the NTFS USB key on a windows 7 machine. Assuming that the device is named 'usbkey' and the disk shows up as /dev/disk1:

```
$ sudo umount /Volumes/usbkey
$ sudo mkdir /Volumes/usbkey
$ sudo mount -t ntfs -w -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk1 /Volumes/usbkey
$ mount | grep usbkey
/dev/disk1 on /Volumes/usbkey (ntfs, local, noowners, nobrowse)
```

I was able to copy files to and from the NTFS formated drive using Terminal, and if I ran 'open .' from the /Volumes/usbkey location in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me on Yosemite. No 3rd drivers needed!
http://sourceforge.net/projects/native-ntfs-osx/files/