# Do we need FUSE apps in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, unix, ntfs

I just heard from my friend that all those FUSE apps are not needed anymore in Mavericks. Is that true? I have, from the previous version of OS X: MacFUSE, FUSE for OS X, fuse-ext2, NTFS-3G. Do I still need them? If not, how to remove them *completely*?

Comment: What are you trying to do? (And if you need uninstallation advice, consider listing what you installed if you know of it as there are several forks of the FUSE project even on OS X - http://fuse.sourceforge.net)

Comment: I listed all that live on my system: MacFUSE, FUSE for OS X, fuse-ext2, NTFS-3G. Since I am (occasionally) using both Linux and Win based systems.
My question is do I need any of these on the latest Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacFUSE is no longer being developed, and there's many bugs with it in Mavericks. FUSE for OS X was the continuation of this development and still works well in Mavericks. I recommend that you uninstall MacFUSE and instead use FUSE for OS X.

ntfs-3g in Mavericks requires this install procedure:

- [Write in NTFS using Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106589/write-in-ntfs-using-mavericks)

You should know if you need FUSE — if you don't need it, there are official removal instructions:

- https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ#23-how-can-i-uninstall-fuse-for-os-x

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! However, my question was, actually, whether we still need these apps for r/w access to ext2 (ext3) and ntfs?