# Duplicated volume name bug with NTFS-formated drives on Yosemite

Tags: macos, ntfs

I used this solution, [Write to NTFS-formated drives on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180248/4007), but after system restart have strange bug with names for NTFS drives - every next reboot I see new number right after volume's name. E.g. at first it was DISTRIB, after next reboot - DISTRIB 1, next time DISTRIB  2 and...

Any ideas?

Comment: Download an install the latest [FUSE for OS X](https://osxfuse.github.io) from a standard installer package.

Comment: Just got 3.1.0 from here (https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases) installed. Rebooted. Still the same bug. Any additional things have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it by updating to 3.1.0 (thanx guys) and deleting alias icons. After system reboot my volumes got their original names

Answer (score 0):

This duplicating of volume names appears to be a known issue in FUSE for OS X that has been fixed in more recent versions.

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/119

The Homebrew cask system is still installing 2.x versions but if you install one of the pre-release 3.x versions from GitHub the issue is reported to have been fixed.

Comment: Still have this bug. Strange...

Comment: The new version might fix the problem but not be smart enough to tidy up. Try unmounting/unplugging the NTFS drive then deleting the extra folders under /Volumes, reboot and try plugging the drive in again.

Comment: Done it. But had no extra folders there. After reboot drives have pugged automatically and kept names as they were before unplugging and rebooting

Comment: I'm not clear, are you saying the problem is fixed or not? :) Is the name still incrementing after reboots?

Comment: Now I think it is ok, but I don't know how to reset volume name to first state - it is still named "DISTRIB 5". Do you know how to rename it (change mount point name) to "DISTRIB"?