# How to get rid of "The disk you inserted was not readable" and auto ignore it? (without installing apps)

Tags: partition, filesystem, mount, automount

whenever I plug in an ext4 partition type external USB drive, this message will pop up. and then I need to press "Ignore" to ignore it. This is very annoying. How can I auto ignore it?

I did google this for hours and can not find a proper solution. I don't want to install any non open source apps for doing such a simple task. I think it should be doable by changing some config files.

PS: If you are curious why I want to plug in ext4 drive, because I will later use it with a linux VM (virtualbox+vagrant).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edited: I don't want to disable automount for all types of drives. I just want to ignore ext4 popup or that specific drive. Cheers.

Comment: You can mount them with Fuse; which I know isn't the same as ignoring, but might be worth a look at - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210198/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the reply. but I really don't want to mount it at all. Because if I mount it, I won't be able to use it in my VM. All I want is to auto ignore this pop up. cheers.

Comment: Since you want to use it with VirtualBox, why not just create a USB filter in VB and let it grab the USB device?

Comment: @Allan first, I am not sure what USB filter means here, but I don't think that is a proper solution. What if the VM reboots/shutdown? The popup window appears again and again when my VM reboots and shutdown. If USB filter works even when there is no VM running and no virtualbox app running, that will be the solution. cheers.

Comment: I gotta ask... You don't know what USB filter means but you're *sure* it won't work?  See this question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/183003/119271

Comment: @Allan I read that page. I have been using USB Filter a long long time ago. I just never pay attention on the `name`. That won't work for sure because that is what I am using right now. When the VM reboots and shutdown, the system popup the warning again and again. I don't think virtualbox will do anything to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Due to no answer yet, I did find a workaround and want to share here.

(1) Resize the external drive and create a small 100MB Apple_HFS typed partition on it. (label the partition with the name `dummy`).

Explanation: Since there is a recognized readable partition in the external drive now, there will be no warning popup at all and will auto mount it as `/Volumes/dummy/`.

(2) Create a shell script in the PATH with the name `vagrant-up.sh` which has the following content:

```
diskutil umount /Volumes/dummy/ && cd ~/vagrant/myVM/ && vagrant up
```

So to run my vm, simply execute `vagrant-up.sh`.

That's all. It works well so far.