# Which filesystems support symbolic links?

Tags: hard-drive, unix, filesystem, symlink

I'm copying a big archive of files from a Linux host to an external USB hard drive, that will then plug into a macOS host.  The copy should preserve the archive's many symbolic links (`ln -s`).  What filesystem should I format the external disk as?

- Not exFAT, because that doesn't support symlinks.
- ext4 can be mounted only read-only, via e.g. [ext4fuse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251611/49582).
- Something else, that can mount read-write?  (Must also be writable by the original Linux host, Ubuntu 16.04.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HFS+ (Mac OS Extended Journaled)

**Why?**

- Supports Symlinks
- Read/write on macOS natively
- Easy installation for read/write on Linux

*See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os) for Linux installation tutorial.*

Comment: Yes, but disable journalling so Linux can write to it.

Comment: If you format it on Linux with `apt-get install gparted hfsprogs; gparted /dev/sdd` and choosing HFS+ in the menu, then Linux can read and write.