# Is it possible to mount an ext4 partition, Luks encrypted SDCARD on a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, encryption

I saw the question below and now I know that I'm able to mount a EXT4 disk in a MacBook:

[Mount Ext4 on El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210198/mount-ext4-on-el-capitan)

But I do need to mount a LUKS encrypted disk. Is it possible?

Comment: I think this answer still applies: https://superuser.com/questions/110032/how-to-mount-an-encrypted-ext3-filesystem-under-os-x

Comment: I was hoping that after 10 years they might have addressed this gap. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linsk](https://github.com/AlexSSD7/linsk). It is a utility that wraps around a lightweight Alpine Linux VM, allowing you to mount any Linux file system (including **LUKS**) that is then exposed to the host machine through a network file share.

**Disclosure**: I'm the author.