# How can I list the partition table of an unmounted disk image?

Tags: macos, command-line

I want to prepare Raspian Jessie found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) in SD card for Biosignal Pi, instructions found [here](http://biosignalpi.org/index.php/software/development-guide/how-to-install-qt-qwt-and-overclock-rpi), but I have only OS X 10.11.3 El Capitan of Macbook Air 2013-mid now. 
The image is in `fstype` format so it is not compatible with OS X. 
Verifying that using the correct hash by 
`openssl sha1 /Users/masi/code/2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.zip` which gives

```
SHA1(/Users/masi/code/2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.zip)= 4a841dffd02197548bf2329b90a0a44eeeebb4ab
```

which is the correct hash found in the website so not corrupted file.
However, running SHA1 on the .img returns different SHA1 than with David

```
masi$ openssl sha1 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img
SHA1(2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img)= da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

One step requires me to list the partition table of an unmounted disk image. On Linux I would use `fdisk -l`, but OS X `fdisk image.img` gives

```
Disk: 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img    geometry: 0/4/63 [0 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

where you can see that the system does not recognise the image. 
I try to mount the image `2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img` in DiskImageMounter.app application but I get

[image]

Comment: So you basically want to list the partition table of an *unmounted* disk image?

Comment: As already mentioned, please focus on the problem you are trying to solve here. Just adding more details about missing commands etc. will not make the question more clear, as the approach required to solve the problem on OSX might be quite different from Linux (from where the instructions seem to come which you are trying to follow).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hardware may be corrupt. This device has been 5 times under Apple's warranty, but according to Apple, the device should be ok. Motherboard new, SSD new and OS X new. I will put this device once more to Apple if we cannot find out a logical reason for the output.

Comment: You may want to try running `openssl sha1 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img` and compare with my results. Also, the DiskImageMounter.app is not needed. (See my Update 2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To properly get the partition table of a (disk-)image file use:

```
hdiutil imageinfo /path/to/image
```

Example:

```
hdiutil imageinfo /Users/user/Downloads/2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img 

Backing Store Information:
    URL: file:///Users/user/Downloads/2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img
    Name: 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img
    Class Name: CBSDBackingStore
Class Name: CRawDiskImage
Checksum Type: Ohne
Size Information:
    Total Bytes: 4029677568
    Compressed Ratio: 1
    Sector Count: 7870464
    Total Non-Empty Bytes: 4029677568
    Compressed Bytes: 4029677568
    Total Empty Bytes: 0
Format: RAW*
Format Description: Lesen/Schreiben, reine Daten
Checksum Value: 
Properties:
    Encrypted: false
    Kernel Compatible: true
    Checksummed: false
    Software License Agreement: false
    Partitioned: false
    Compressed: no
Segments:
    0: /Users/user/Downloads/2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img
partitions:
    partition-scheme: fdisk
    block-size: 512
    partitions:
        0:
            partition-name: Master Boot Record
            partition-start: 0
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 1
            partition-hint: MBR
            boot-code: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A83FF60C0000
        1:
            partition-name: 
            partition-start: 1
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 8191
            partition-hint: Apple_Free
        2:
            partition-start: 8192
            partition-number: 1
            partition-length: 122880
            partition-hint: Windows_FAT_32
            partition-filesystems:
                FAT16: boot
        3:
            partition-start: 131072
            partition-number: 2
            partition-length: 7739392
            partition-hint: Linux_Ext2FS
    burnable: false
Resize limits (per hdiutil resize -limits):
 min     cur     max 
7870464 7870464 393749544
```

---

Tested with the original image (`shasum -a1` of the never mounted img: 6a9ac027081aa38213ebe1fcf9ed502a6d6ec14e) downloaded [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest).

This works at least in 10.9.5 Mavericks - 10.11.3 El Capitan.

Comment: I get `hdiutil: imageinfo failed - image not recognized` with your first command. Do you have something additional installed?

Comment: @Masi Hmm no I have neither installed osxfuse nor Paragon drivers. Paralles/VMware is installed though.

Comment: @Masi Have you been able to hunt down the error? You either tried to mount the image without locking it or your RAM/Processor/SSD is corrupted. Do you get any errors in the system log?

Comment: No. I just know that some corruption error in RAM/Processor/SSD during the unzipping process. SSD is unlikely but possible. Which logs would you want to look at?

Comment: @Masi You may look in the system log for "I/O error" (SSD). RAM/Proc errors (like flipping bits) are rarely detected. It may also be a bus error. Did you try to mount the locked img (after unzipping it once more)?

Comment: Yes, I did mount it afterwards successfully after I got unzipped the correct .img.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2

Actually, there is no need to use the DiskImageMounter.app. The `fdisk` command can be used directly on the .img file. In other words, the command

```
fdisk 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img
```

produces the same results as when I executed `fdisk /dev/disk2`. When I run the command

```
openssl sha1 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img
```

I get the results shown below.

```
SHA1(2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img)= 6a9ac027081aa38213ebe1fcf9ed502a6d6ec14e
```

I also have a (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) iMac running El Capitan OS X 10.11.3. The results using this computer are the same.

Note that if the `2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img` file is mounted using the DiskImageMounter.app application, the hex value produced by `openssl sha1 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img` changes. **This would indicate the image file is not mounted readonly.**

### Update 1

Since I also have El Capitan OS X 10.11.3 installed on my (20 inch, mid 2007) iMac, I can verify against your machine. Using the command

```
openssl sha1 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.zip
```

the result is

```
SHA1(2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.zip)= 4a841dffd02197548bf2329b90a0a44eeeebb4ab
```

which is the same as your results. The rest is the same as shown below when I used Yosemite.

### Original Answer

I am using Yosemite OS X 10.10.5.

I downloaded `2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.zip`.

Using the Finder application, I right clicked on this file and selected the open with "Archive Utility.app". This created `2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img`.

Using the Finder Application, I right clicked on `2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img` and selected open with DiskImageMounter.app. This mounted at the image as `/dev/disk2` on my Mac.

Here is what is in the the file you downloaded.

```
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ fdisk /dev/disk2
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 976/128/63 [7870464 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0C    0 130   3 -    8  40  32 [      8192 -     122880] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 83    8  40  33 -  489 232  63 [    131072 -    7739392] Linux files*
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ diskutil list /dev/disk2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    62.9 MB    disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         4.0 GB     disk2s2
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$
```

Comment: Did you use the image of the full desktop image found here https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ ? Hmm, it seems to be just some part of your system.

Comment: @Masi: Yes, the full desktop image based on Debian Jessie: 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.zip

Comment: I provided a screenshot about what happens when attempting mounting with DiskImageMounter.app. I verified the hash and it is the same as in the website.

Comment: Your .img SHA is different than mine. Something wrong in unzipping of the system.

Comment: @Masi: Try unzipping the file again. I trying at least a dozen times on two different Macs which produced the same results. Also, your posted results from `fdisk` would indicate the beginning of your image file contains all zeros. I used the "Archive Utility.app" application to unzip the file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have it on the command line?  If not, I would use Disk Utility.

Comment: I updated the body. I could not mount the image by Disk Utility. There is no such a feature as mount the .img file in the application

Comment: Ah; I didn't realize you were trying to mount an .img file.  I thought you were trying to see all the partitions on the system.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

What you are looking to do is list all of the partitions of a disk image that you downloaded.

OS X isn't going to mount any ol' filesystem.  Natively, it will mount HFS, HFS+, CDFS, FAT 16, FAT32, and ExtFAT and read/write.  It will mount NTFS as read-only.

What filesystem does your image use?  Since it is Linux based, it could be Ext2/3/4.  Have a look at [fuse-ext2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/) and [fuse-ext4](http://fuse4x.github.io/).

You can find more details here:  [How can I mount an ext4 file system on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x)

Once you install the drivers for the Linux file syste, you will be able to mount the image.

### 2nd Update:

> I want to setup Biosignal Pi system in SD card. For that, I need to
>   prepare the card in my system.

Now that we know what you are trying to do, you don't need to *mount* the image, you need to *copy* it to your SD.

Basically, what you are going to do is

- insert your SD Card
- use `diskutil list` to list all the drives/partitions to **find** the SD card (it will be /dev/diskX where X is some integer).  The easiest way to do this is to issue the command without the SD card inserted, and then again with it inserted and compare the output. The new entry will be your SD card.
- use `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX` to unmount (not eject) your SD card (so you can write to it)
- use `dd` to copy the image from the file you downloaded to the SD
  card.  Use the command:  use the command:
  `sudo dd bs=1m if=path_of_your_image.img of=/dev/diskX`
- use `diskutil eject /dev/diskX` to eject your SD card so you can use it in your
  Raspberry-Pi device.

These is the "quick guide" that gives you the essentials.  Follow these more in depth instruction as provided by the Raspberry-Pi Download Page for Mac OS X:  [INSTALLING OPERATING SYSTEM IMAGES ON MAC OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)

Those instructions are specific to the file you are attempting to install.

In  your original question , you wanted to list all the partitions under OS X, just use the CLI for `diskutil`

`$ diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage iMacInternalStorage     999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage iMacInternalStorage     121.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS iMac HD                +1.1 TB     disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 7A85AA25-03A0-4C4B-91F5-533D962DCFA1
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: I have just an image i.e. 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img. How can you use your method with it? I could not mount the image in the system for some reason. I will update the body.

Comment: Why are you trying to mount this image?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. You don't need any file system (e.g hfs+ or ext4) driver to read a partition table of a disk.

Comment: @klanomath - If it's an image written in a fstype not compatible with OS X he does.  He can't read it now so that pretty much tosses your argument out a window.  Secondly, I have a dual boot X Serve with OS X and FreeBSD UFS file system.  OS X cannot see the multiple UFS partitions.  Can't read it, period.

Comment: @Allan Can you please add an explanation about `fstype` in your answer. Your last comment is helpful.

Comment: @Masi  Sure...not sure if I understand the qustion...what are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @Allan Just check my answer. All partitions are listed!

Comment: @Allan Just to prepare the SD card of Raspian with OS X.

Comment: @klanomath then you have something additional installed because I can't and he can't

Comment: @klanomath...one more thing...this entire thread is moot because his question and what he wanted to do are two totally different things.  Ultimately (after many edits on the OP's part), he wanted to copy the image to his SD card...which is what I answered in my 2nd Update.