# How do I grant permission to edit a file on an SD card?

Tags: permission, unix, sd-card

I flashed Ubuntu server to an SD card on my MacBook Pro with the Raspberry Pi OS flashing application. I want to edit the network-config file to put in the WiFi information. When I view this file in TextEdit, I cannot save it, even though when I press "Get Info" it says I have read and write permissions. When I try to edit it in Vim, similarly, I get "permission denied".

How can I grant permission to edit this file?

Comment: What format is the SD card?

Comment: It was erased and formatted to MS-DOS in Disk Utility. Then it was erased and written to again by the Raspberry Pi application.

Comment: It's going to be ExtFS which the Mac can't write to natively - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x

Comment: I guess so - that post says that Macs cannot edit that disk format, so I will have to use a Linux virtual machine. If that is the answer, then yes, it answers my question. However, if there is any easier way, like using a different format, while still being able to write a bootable operating system to the disk, I would be interested in hearing it.